# Possible to specify event listeners for environment?

Tags: laravel, events

I'm making my first laravel application, and I have a UpdateLoginInfo class that updates the user's last_login value and increments a count of how many times they've logged in.  I listen for it during auth.login, in EventServiceProvider, like so:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        'auth.login' => [
            'App\Events\UpdateLoginInfo',
        ],
    ];
```

It's working great, but while testing it would be good to be able to log in as different users without affecting their counts (but I use the same database for my sandbox and production).  I'm wondering if there's a way to specify environment so that the listener only happens in production and is ignored in my sandbox- is this a legitimate thing to try to do (and if yes, how)?  Or is it ugly and I should think about making/using another database for my testing environment?

Comment: You really **should** use a different database for testing purposes, using the production database for anything other than production is like playing with fire, no matter how careful you are you can always mess it up.

Comment: If you need to test against data collected in production, cloning the database can be as easy as running `mysqldump production_database | mysql test_database` in your terminal. (this assumes you're using MySQL of course :) ).

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan- I'm using postgres, but I have a feeling you're right... I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use environment to check before you increase the count.
Refer to main docs
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/#basic-configuration

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // The environment is local
}

if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```